# Get part of string in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, string

I need get part of a string in MySQL, to put it inside a trigger where this part of a string is a key for another table and will be use as foreign key

The string looks like: `P####PR####` where # is a number, after 'PR' the numbers are an ID for another table where a I need save, but... the size of the number parts is variable like

```
P1PR20
P20PR321
P4321PR54321
P1PR1
```

I need remove all characters of this string before do last numeric part

```
P1PR20        -> 20
P20PR321      -> 321
P4321PR54321  -> 54321
P1PR1         -> 1
```

please, any suggestion?

Comment: You can get a substring from the last index of 'PR' to the end of the string. Unfortunately I can't put up a full answer but I'm sure someone else will, or you can google something like "MySQL SUBSTRING function"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suppose you have a pattern P####PR#### (as you said in your question), so

Try this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(field, INSTR(field, 'PR') + 2, 100)
FROM dual
```

**EDIT**

`INSTR(field, 'PR')` <-- get the index of first occurence of PR. In your cases:

If you have:

`P1PR20` the value of function is 3

`P20PR321` the value of function is 4.

I add 2 because I must to position on the first char after PR.

In the first case:

You have SUBSTRING(field, 3 + 2, 100) --> 20

In the second case:

You have SUBSTRING(field, 4 + 2, 100) --> 321

100 is a generic offset

Comment: It's almost this, but the size of numbers before PR is variable too, it can be P20PR20 OR P321PR20

Comment: Yes, but I take the index of PR, now update my answer to better explain my strategy